# Select specific field of nested HABTM array

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a tickets table, and a contacts table. A ticket can have many contacts.

I am paginating the tickets table, and want it to select specific fields including the first linked contact form the nested array. No matter what I try, I can't seem to figure this one out (or if it is even possible).

My code:

```
$this->paginate = array(<br>
    'conditions' => array('status_id !=' => '3'),<br>
    'limit'=>50,<br>
    'fields'=>array('Ticket.title', 'Ticket.ticket_number', 'Priority.name', 'Status.name', 'Contact.0.full_name')  <br>            
);
```

(The Contact.0.full_name is causing it to fail. How can I make this work?)

So I can use this column with `$this->Paginator->sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You **cant** call columns like this `Contact.0.full_name` CakePHP doesn't work like that. A valid field name is `TableAlias.column_name`

You cant use `hasMany` relation's children into sort operation.

To achieve similar functionality, You can drop `hasMany` and add `hasOne` to achieve the desired output. Because there's no schema changes in both relationship types.

```
$this->Ticket->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Contact')));
$this->Ticket->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Contact')));
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('status_id !=' => '3'),
    'limit'=>50,
    'fields'=>array('Ticket.title', 'Ticket.ticket_number', 'Priority.name',  'Status.name', 'Contact.full_name')
);
```

Now you can use this column `Contact.full_name` for sorting purposes.

Comment: Thanks Ish, the problem is that I need to get the contacts full_name from the paginate query so that I have the option to sort the results from my index page using $this->Paginator->sort...

Comment: @user612048 You need drop & add relationship on fly, try updated (*I haven't tested it*)

Comment: ... not sure what you are saying, and searches are coming up empty.. can  you point me in the right direction?